# php text box enter event

Tags: php, html, textbox, autocomplete, autosuggest

i was created one text box and autosuggestion in json used php. enter text box input "a" and autosuggestion output "a" related keywords, i was select any one keyword using keyboard "Down arrow or Up arrow" and "Enter" key pressed. the form action GET method post only "a" letter, not selected words. i want selected words post in GET method. please help me.....

Notes: Select one key word using "Mouse pointer" and GET method post selected words but key board using wrong answer.

Comment: he wants that users should be able to using keyboard return key too to select an item from suggestion, and once they select form should be submitted with GET method i suppose.

Comment: I am assuming he wants something like Google Suggest...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [jquery library](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin).

Please not that certain browser such as firefox, have the build in autosuggest feature, that sometimes will interfere the autocomplete from plugins. You can disable it using `<input type="text" autocomplete="off" ... />`